How does Stokes formula extend to finite volume polygons with a vertex at infinity in the hyperbolic upper plane?
The motivation of this question comes from the beginning of Chapter 4 of Iwaniec's "Spectral methods of automorphic forms" (2nd edition), regarding the symmetry of the automorphic laplacian $\Delta$ on $D(\Gamma/\mathbb{H})$= {$f \in A(\Gamma/\mathbb{H}): \ f,\ \Delta f$ smooth and bounded}, for a Fuchsian group $\Gamma$.
For a bounded domain $F$ in $\mathbb{H}$ with piecewise smooth boundary, $f,g \in D(\Gamma / \mathbb H$)
$$\int_{F}\Delta f\ \bar{g} \ d\mu z=-\int_{F}\nabla f \cdot \nabla \bar{g}\ dxdy+\int_{\partial F}\frac{\partial f}{\partial \textbf{n}}\bar{g}\ d\textbf{l} $$
where $d\mu z$ is the hyperbolic area element, $\nabla$ is the gradient, $\frac{\partial}{\partial \textbf{n}}=y\frac{\partial}{\partial n}$ where $\frac{\partial}{\partial n}$ is the outer normal derivative and $d\textbf{l}=y^{-1}dl$ with $dl$ euclidean metric.
It is claimed that in this form Stokes theorem holds if we take $F$ a finite area fundamental polygon. In particular since the integrand in the boundary term is hyperbolic invariant, the boundary term vanishes as integrals along equivalent sides of $\partial F$ cancel out.
I would like to understand why this is true: in order to obtain the cancellation of the boundary term we first need to know that the integral along each side is finite. For some fundamental domains, eg $SL_2(\mathbb Z)$, there are vertices at infinity (or an arbitrary cusp), so I would assume some bound on $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \textbf{n}}$ is needed.
I would also like to know if it is possible to weaken the condition on $f$ and $g$, for instance requiring $f\in D{(\Gamma/\mathbb H)}$ and $g$ having "moderate growth" instead.
